# How is posting fights involving minors not Illegal?

Tags: freedom-of-speech, children, child-abuse

If you visit r/DocumentedFights, r/fightporn and a few other sections of Reddit you see videos of Kids/Teenagers posted fighting a street fight as competitive sport (I dont even have words to describe it) and a lot of which are not even random incidents. Its more like a organized school fight. How is that even entertained by Reddit? I just find something wrong about any fight beyond competitive sports but these videos are more nauseous when the individuals fighting are kids. It looks like a ego trip for posters and some of the individuals involved in uploading in these videos. Even worse are people commenting or getting entertainment from these fights. I think the moderators and users of these sub-reddit are into fight porn which I don't have anything against but a line should be drawn where there is a doubt about the peoples age.

Surely as a platform Reddit cant hide against it being a platform of free speech in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that something is illegal does not imply that it is illegal to post pictures of it happening. In general, under U.S. law, free speech protects almost all forms of communications subject to a handful of narrow exceptions and this is not one of them.

There are many legitimate reasons one might want to post video of a fight (e.g. to identify crime perpetrators for purposes of prosecuting them), but no legitimate purpose is legally necessary.

> Surely as a platform Reddit cant hide against it being a platform of
> free speech in this case?

They most definitely can. Reddit is also not responsible for user posted content under [Section 230 of the Communication Decency Act](https://www.eff.org/issues/cda230), even if it were illegal for the person posting it to post the content

Comment: So it is Legal to post child porn by consenting kids then and the platform has no responsibility to moderate that. Should therefore bars and clubs have no requirement to check ids as they are a platform as well???

Comment: @Uint256 not necessarily. Porn and fight videos are not the same thing. You may consider them morally similar, but that doesn't mean that the law sees them as equivalent or indistinguishable.

Comment: @RobertColumbia So why is a website not a premise just like a bar? And isnt that a flaw in the law? Somethings are just not allowed for minors and if that is happening in your premise its your responsibility as an adult to moderate.

Comment: @Uint256 your question doesn't make sense. The law does not bow to your strict interpretation of morality.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Its not my interpretation of Morality its a question about the Laws interpretation of a Platform. I believe a Website and a Premise are both platforms in their own sense. Whats your opinion on that?

Comment: @Uint256 I believe your belief is wrong. And so do the courts.

Comment: @Uint256 The whole point of Section 230 is to declare as a matter of U.S. federal law that a website is not a premises, after early caselaw before it was adopted ruled otherwise in some cases, while taking the position that Section 230 adopted in others.